# How to put video on top of image

Tags: html

What is the correct HTML to put a video on top of a larger image and have it be centered within the image both horizontally and vertically?

Here is the code for the video:

```
<br>
<div style="float:right;">
  <div id="ext-gen1825" autoplay="false" height="187" width="224" class="ddcPlayer-holder" style="-moz-user-select: none; background-color: #515151; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center;width: 224px;height: 187px;background-image: url(http://videos2.dealer.com/clients/b/baierlautomotivemars/b9716e230a0d02b7010c94a788f23c9e_clicktoplay_en_US.png);" ddcplayerinfo="http://videos2.dealer.com/clients/b/baierlautomotivemars/b9716e230a0d02b7010c94a788f23c9e.xml-224px-187px">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the code for the image:

```
<img id="ext-gen2174" src="http://pictures.dealer.com/b/baierlusedcars/0487/31f397280a0d02b700ae8af470747bb2.png"href="http://pictures.dealer.com/b/baierlusedcars/0487/31f397280a0d02b700ae8af470747bb2.png" title="Better Story.png" class="wysiwyg-image" tabindex="30000" style="height: 202px; width: 236px;">
```

Comment: What does your code look like? What have you tried?

Comment: How can I get my code to show up on this site?

Comment: Edit your question and paste it in. Or link to it from a site like jsFiddle.net or jsbin.com

Comment: Added your code from the raw edit logs.  Please review formatting guide, it will help you.  In this case you are trying to paste code and need to add it as a code block.  This is done by indenting all lines by four spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Without code, it can be difficult to know exactly what you're looking for... There are different ways to accomplish this.

Have a div with the background-image and the video inside this div.

Also;

Have a div with your image with `position: relative;` , have a div inside that div with your video and set `position: absolute;`. Set top and left css attributes accordingly (50%, but sometimes you might want less).

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to do this is with a table. The table will have only one cell and you pad the cell, this will center the image automatically for you. I used iframe below because that is the default code for an embedded video from youtube.

```
<table background="http://www.example.com/images/example.jpg" cellpadding=50>
<tr>
<td>
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/te6qG4yn-Ps"  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Tables for layout? `background` attributes? `your.years += 15;`!

Comment: Hey, it answers the question in a simple fashion. Just because its from web 1.0 doesn't mean it doesn't work. Its perfect for centering.

Comment: A `<div>` with a `background-image` would actually be _simpler_ than a table.

Comment: Tried the table - it just puts the picture underneath the video, not the video on top of the picture.

Comment: Help me understand the difference?
[Layer 1: Picture]
[Layer 2: Video].
Picture layer<Video layer is the same as Video Layer > Picture Layer. Right?

Comment: As in it you can see both the video and the full picture underneath - not layered underneath, but directly placed underneath as if I put a line break in between the two.

Comment: Ahh, in that case this code will not work and you should definitely use <div>s and CSS.

Comment: Also, if the picture is underneath the video, how can it be centered both horizontally and vertically? If its underneath, you can only center it horizontally (i.e, if the video gets taller, it does not effect the position of the picture other than moving it down the page). Am I interpreting your question correctly?

Comment: I want the picture centered horizontally and I want the video layered on top of that centered horizontally AND vertically within the picture (so it is in the exact middle of the picture)  That make sense?